# Problem with defining function and use it in animate

Tags: differential-equations, animation

I can't animate this code, what's wrong and how can I write omega, theta,...
If I copy XG1 and YG1 directly in animate it works properly but when I use defined function(XG1 and YG1) it can't works.

```
ClearAll[L, t, V, θ1] 
m1 = 1;
m2 = 1;
I1 = 1;
L1 = 1;
LC1 = L1/2;
R = 0.3;
L2 = 1;

XG1[t_] := +R*Sin[θ1[t]] - LC1*Cos[θ1[t]];
YG1[t_] := -R*Cos[θ1[t]] - LC1*Sin[θ1[t]];



ω1[t_] = D[θ1[t], t];

T1 = 0;

T = 1/2*m1*((D[XG1, t])^2 + (D[YG1, t])^2) + 1/2*I1*ω1^2;
V = m1*g*YG1;

L = T - V;
Eq = D[D[L, θ1'[t]], t] - D[L, θ1[t]] == T1;
ics = {θ1[0] == 0, θ1'[0] == 0};
eqs = Join[{Eq}, ics];

s = First@NDSolve[eqs, {θ1[t], θ1'[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];



Animate[Graphics[{Line[{{0,0},{XG1, YG1}}]}], {t, 0.01, 50}] /. s
```

Comment: You have so many errors before you even get to the animation part. Your Lagrangian is not even function of time. You should evaluate each step one by one and make sure it is correct before you go to the next step. You define w1 as function of time, but you do not use that fact when you reference it. Many other problems like this.

Comment: To write the greek letters, hit Esc, type Omega, then hit Esc again. For small letter use omega. Alternatively you can go to Palettes -> Special characters.

Comment: this code work properly when I use  +R*Sin[θ1[t]] - LC1*Cos[θ1[t]] instead of XG1 but when I use XG1 and YG1  it doesn't work. I defined XG1 but it can't work in last line!!!!

Comment: I doubt it. As mentioned by Nasser, your code is full of errors. Even after correcting those, your `Animate` command does not produced anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code that is similar to yours, but with a few fixes:

1. Specify `g=1/6`
2. Remove $\omega$ and use $\theta'$ instead
3. `NDSolve[]` for $\theta$ and $\theta'$ instead of $\theta[t]$ and $\theta'[t]$
4. Move `/.s` inside of `Animate[]`, just after `Graphics[]`
5. Add a `Rectangle[]` to the background of the graphics 
   to prevent zoom changes.
6. Add arguments `[t]` to functions `XG1` and `YG1` inside `Graphics[]`

Try this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

m1 = 1; m2 = 1; I1 = 1;
L1 = 1; LC1 = L1/2;
R = 0.3; L2 = 1; g = 1/6;

XG1[t_] := +R*Sin[θ1[t]] - LC1*Cos[θ1[t]]
YG1[t_] := -R*Cos[θ1[t]] - LC1*Sin[θ1[t]]
T1 = 0;
T = 1/2*m1*((D[XG1[t], t])^2 + (D[YG1[t], t])^2) +
   1/2*I1*θ1'[t]^2;
V = m1*g*YG1[t];

L = T - V;
Eq = D[D[L, θ1'[t]], t] - D[L, θ1[t]] == T1;
ics = {θ1[0] == 0, θ1'[0] == 0};
eqs = Join[{Eq}, ics];

s = First@NDSolve[eqs, {θ1, θ1'}, {t, 0, 100}];

Animate[Graphics[{PointSize[1/25],
    Line[{{0, 0}, {XG1[t], YG1[t]}}],
    Point[{XG1[t], YG1[t]}],
    Opacity[1/10], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]},
   Frame -> True] /. s, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: Thanks Louis. Its work exactly my friend.

Comment: what is difference between teta and teta[t] in NDsolve

Comment: @Farshid An excellent question!  All of the examples in the [documentation for `NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html), indicate we should solve for `y` and then `Plot[y[x], ...]`.  It is possible to `NDSolve` for `y[x]` and then `Plot[y[x]/.s, ...]`, at least in some cases.  I do not know why that does not work here.  You may find the answer by studying the simplest possible example, or by searching this site for questions about `NDSolve`.  If that doesn't work, please ask this as a new question.